# How do you both POST data to a node server and GET a responseText from it?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, http, express

In the following example, I am attempting to send data from a javascript client to an Express node server, verify the data
against the db on the server and respond once the verification is complete. The data object in newHttpRequest.send(data)
contains JSON formatted paired values.

In the example below, the POST command sends the data object to the server using the specified path. This works well. What
it does not do is send a response back to the client verifying the data. When I run the code example, the ready state never
gets past 1 (server connection established). If I change the POST parameter to GET, the ready state progresses from 1 to 2 to 3
to 4 as you would expect with a responseText value based on whatever the path is set to. The problem with the GET command is
that the data is never sent from the client or received by the server.

My question is, can I not both POST data to a node server and GET a responseText from it stating that the data has been successfully
verified?

```
{ // XMLHttpRequest
  var newHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var path = "http://00.0.0.00:80";

  newHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    alert("onreadystatechange: " + newHttpRequest.readyState );
    if ( newHttpRequest.readyState === 4 && newHttpRequest.status === 200)
    {
      var myResponseText = newHttpRequest.responseText;
      alert ("responseText: " + myResponseText);
    }
  };

  newHttpRequest.open("POST", path, true);
  newHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
  newHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("header_nb", "1");
  newHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("header_ds", "logon");
  newHttpRequest.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8" );
  newHttpRequest.send(data);
} // eof code block
```

Comment: What is your server sude code ? Dou you have a route handler to handle GET request to http://00.0.0.00:80 ?

Comment: The problem might be with your server code. You can send data along with your response ,for the POST request itself. Using express you can do something like `res.send("resText")` to send response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send either a POST or a GET request at a time. You can get (receive) data from the server after sending a POST or you can send a GET after a sending a POST to receive some other data; it's just semantics :)

Here is an example that I hope will help you out:

Frontend (index.html + your modified script):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    { // XMLHttpRequest
        var newHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var path = "http://0.0.0.0:3000";

        newHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            alert("onreadystatechange: " + newHttpRequest.readyState );
            if ( newHttpRequest.readyState === 4 && newHttpRequest.status === 418)
            {
                var myResponseText = newHttpRequest.responseText;
                alert ("responseText: " + myResponseText);
            }
        };

        var data = {
            hero: 'Spiderman Spiderman',
            ability: 'He can open a tuna can'
        };

        newHttpRequest.open("POST", path + '/my-post-route', true);
        newHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        newHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("header_nb", "1");
        newHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("header_ds", "logon");
        newHttpRequest.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8" );
        newHttpRequest.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Backend (index.js, node+express):

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var app = express();

// Configure express settings; standard stuff; research what they do if you don't know
app.set('trust proxy', true);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '10mb', extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '10mb'}));
app.use(cookieParser());

// Configure routes
app.post('/my-post-route', function (req, res, next) {
    // ... do what you need to do here ...

    console.log(req.headers); // to see what those headers contain

    console.log(req.body); // Look ma! It's Spiderman!

    var ImATeaPot = true;

    if (ImATeaPot)
        return res.status(418).send("I'm a teapot!"); // return to end here (if you are a teapot) and send a string; you can chain status, send and other commands

    res.send("I'm not a teapot! :O"); // Oh yes you are! 
    // send status is 200 by default, so you don't need to set it if that's what you need

    // res.json({ myText: "Hello World!" }); // you can send an object with .json(); also status 200 by default
    // res.status(500).end(); // you can just send a status and no body; always remember to send something or end it or next() if you want to keep going with some other express code
});

// for testing purposes we send the index.html
app.get('/*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html'));

// Start the server; Listen for requests on the desired port
var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    return console.log('Hello World!');
});

module.exports = server;
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.14.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.0",
    "express": "^4.12.2"
  }
}
```

In the terminal:

```
npm install
node index.js
```

In the browser, go to 0.0.0.0:3000

Comment: Thanks man. As you say you must either GET or POST, you can't do both at the same time. I suppose this only makes sense. This has given me some good ideas on how to proceed.  Appreciate the detailed response. Cheers...

Comment: Hey, I'm glad it helped you out. If it's all good, you can accept this as the answer to your question to wrap it up, otherwise it stays open ;)

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems here. First, You might need to add timeout in POST call to receive response. The server has to respond to POST requests or else you will get timeout error or Internal server error(500).

Second, You can not use POST and GET in the same call. When you use GET instead of POST, the data becomes irrelevant because it's a GET call in which data is not sent to remote end. This is why you are receiving quick response to GET call probably.

In my view, you should verify remote HTTP server will curl command once.

Comment: Gaurav, hi and thanks for your input.  A couple of points: 1) I am not getting a HttpRequest.status === 500 when I run the POST command. As I mentioned in my question the data is successfully POSTed to the server. The problem is (and the basis of my question) that I do not get a responseText. Are you suggesting that I will if I add a timeout? 2) Yes I am getting a fast (and what looks to be a correct) response using the GET call including the fact that I 'GET' what looks to be the correct responseText. So, I'm not sure that this is consistent with you response?